# Using typedef and typename inside a template

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, derived, typename

I want to define a type name in a templated class that I can use elsewhere to refer to the type of a member in the class.

```
template <class T>
class CA
{
public:
    //typedef typename T::iterator iterator_type;
    typedef typename T ElementType1; // compile error on this line
    //typedef T ElementType2;

    T m_element;
};
```

and use it like this:

```
template <class T>
class CDerived : public CBase<typename T::ElementType1>
{
 //...
};
```

and declare objects like:

```
typedef CDerived<CA> MyNewClass;
```

Is this not possible? I have some code that compiles correctly under VS2010 but not under Xcode that uses the line:

```
typedef typename T ElementType1;
```

Apparently the compiler is expecting a qualified name after typename but I don't see how there can be one for the template type.

I dont understand the difference between ElementType1 and ElementType2 in this context.

I looked at many questions on stack overflow but most seemed to refer to only the kind of declaration like iterator_type in my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler already knows `T` is a type (`class T`), so you don't need the `typename` qualifier in the first case. OTOH, the compiler doesn't know in advance that `T::ElementType1` is a type; it depends on what T ends up being.

Comment: OK cool that answers my question, I need to just use `typedef T ElementType`. Really I wasn't sure if typename should be in there or not. I understand its use in the `CBase<typename T::ElementType>`. Here is more info about type name [link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html). It seems like VS2010 accepts the ElementType1 declaration however, but perhaps not gcc.

Answer (score 4):

`typename` can only be used to qualify a qualified name; it doesn't
apply the the name immediately following it, but to the qualified name,
i.e. in:

```
typedef typename T::X x;
```

the `typename` applies to the `X`, and not the `T`.  For this reason, it
is only legal (in this use) before qualified names.  Non-qualified names
must be in a context where the compiler can know whether the name is a
type or not.  (In practice, this is only an issue in types defined in a 
dependent base class, and these can be qualified.)